# Is there any way to POST forms to the external site?

Tags: php, json, curl, web

I must create a simple app to:

1. create input with my variable (NIP)
2. connect to site [https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl](https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/appBIR/index.aspx)
3. somehowe show in my app Captcha code from there and able to fill in and POST to above site
4. search there "NIP" POSTed from my app and show results

I tried to get content by cURL and JS but as we know there's Same Origin Policy protection... Posting by JSON ends the same.
Now I'm stuck and don't even know how to do it. Anybody have any ideas?
Thanks for any help how to can create it.

Comment: why do you want to use a remote captcha/script/image source? It's evil.

Comment: Same origin policy as I know it applies to scripts on client side. Why do you tag this question with `java` ? You can use `cURL` to post to another site, if you know what all the parameters that need to be sent.

Comment: @Stefan I'm doing it to pass test to new job, and this is TODO list which i recieved.

Comment: @frz3993 When i'm trying cURL i got error "[errmsg] => SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: So cURL has problem with your SSL cert. Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` If this curl option work, you should get the root CA cert.

Comment: Which language / infrastructure ? You can solve this with a reverse proxy or serverside language like Java

Comment: @frz3993 still same err

Comment: @Marged any progr language :)

Comment: @botan no, select a language. It makes no sense to give you a readymade solution you are not able to explain. I would fire you instantly if I caught you "cheating" this way

Comment: @Marged Could be PHP but i think this will be hard. Then i will try to make it in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

How about AJAX-Request via JQuery?

Links:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "http://www.stat.gov.pl/regon/",
  data: { name: "John", password: "XXXXX" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Your Response:" + msg );
  });
```

Comment: Using JSON end with „Same Origin Policy” every time.